# Converting array to string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I used numpy to do this. I have a text file containing a series of numbers:

```
[  11.1   44.0   74.9  103.8  115.8
  157.0   170.1  208.4   239.9  296.8]
```

How do I convert the text file to:

```
11.10377777 44.03133786 74.9749492 103.83874619 115.83058441 157.0862515 170.10200524 208.4376871 239.90138829 296.86073327
```

```
stim = a[0,61:71] 
stim2 = a[0,21]
fname = 'blah'
f_events = open('L:\\directory\\' + blah + '.txt',"w")
f_events.write(str(stim-stim2))
f_events.close()
```

Comment: Also, there are three spaces between each number, but I want it to be 1 space.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that's the answer; why don't you submit it?

Comment: go ahead and accept answer if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use " ".[join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) ... but you need to [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) your floats to string inside the join

```
with open('L:\\directory\\' + blah + '.txt',"w" ) as f_events:
    f_events.write(" ".join(map(str,stim-stim2)))  #this line :)
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your solution so that it uses `with open(...) as f:` instead of the explicit `.close()`?

Comment: I'd add that if you want some more customization(e.g. print only first x decimal places), you can use string formatting to get the desired result. Even though this doesn't seem required by the OP.

Comment: there used with instead (better form... but unrelated to OP)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using numpy, just use `np.savetxt`, really should first check what the packages you use provide...